# get the value of a checkbox then pass it to a link to edit a page

Tags: php, checkbox, row, hyperlink

I have been working on this script that should get the value of an id field in a database through a checkbox that will be used by a link to edit a page. I know there are topics relating to this but non deals with using the value of the checkbox in a link. The checkbox is actually getting the value of the id from the database i know this because i used inspect element in firefox to view the value of the checkbox. **The issue I'm having is using this value in a link to edit a page.** Any help will be appreciated. My script is displayed below.

```
     <td width="341" height="73"><h1><strong><span class="style2">EVENTS </span></strong></h1></td>
     <td width="59" align="right"><div align="right"><strong>New</strong></div></td>
     <td width="66" align="right"><div align="right"><strong><a href="edit_event.php?id=<?php 
     if (isset ($chek)) {
         echo urlencode($chek);
     }
     ?>"/>Edit</a></strong></div></td>
     <td width="82" align="right"><div align="right"><strong>Archive</strong></div></td>
     <td width="79" align="right"><div align="right"><strong>Unarchive</strong></div></td>
     <td width="70" align="right"><div align="right"><strong>Delete</strong></div></td>
     <td width="71" align="right"><div align="right"><strong>Exit</strong></div></td>
 </tr>

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="786" border="1">
    <tr valign="top">
    <th width="46">Event Title</th>
    <th width="27"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox" /></th>
    <th width="37">Start Date</th>
    <th width="36">End Date</th>
    <th width="43">Start Time</th>
    <th width="38">End Time</th>
    <th width="43">Venue</th>
    <th width="45">Event Type</th>
    <th width="94">Event Description</th>
    <th width="152">Event Program</th>
    <th width="79">Reminder Date</th>
    <th width="70">Reminder Time</th>   
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
    <tr valign="top">
    <td><?php echo $event->event_title; ?></td>
    <td> <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <?php echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chek[]\" value= $event->event_id  id=\"chek\"/>"; ?>
    </form>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $event->start_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->end_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->start_time; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->end_time; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->venue; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->event_type; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->event_description; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->event_program; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->reminder_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->reminder_time; ?></td>       
    </tr>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php
        $check = $_POST['chek'];
        if(empty($check)){
        $$check="";
        }else{
             $N = count($check);

             for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
                 $chek =($check[$i]);
             }
       }
?>
```

I don't know if my question is understood, what i meant is that I want the value of my check box to display after  `(http://localhost/emgt/admin/edit_event.php?id=)` id so i can edit that particular row.

Comment: Can someone give me a solution to this problem? I have been working on this for more than 8hours with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link. It may be helpful for you.

As far I see you need to add class, and id to your checkbox and use a jquery/javascript function to call the value in your href.

[Pass checkbox value to Edit (using href)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330367/pass-checkbox-value-to-edit-using-href)

Hope it would be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i found your code to be a little unclear. If you mean calling a url with the checkbox value as a parameter you can do so by adding an "id" property to the checkbox element, and then calling the page like:

```
var chk = document.getElementById("checkbox_id");
var url = "http://localhost/emgt/admin/edit_event.php?id=" + chk.value;
location.href = url;
```