# Pass checkbox value to Edit (using href)

Tags: javascript, variables, checkbox, href

I'm trying to get the value of the selected checkbox to be transfered to the next page using href. I'm not in a position to use submit buttons.I want this to be done using JavaScript.

My checkbox is populated with value from a table row-docid. Here is my code for Checkbox in view.php:

```
... mysql_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $doctbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result ){ die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error()); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  ?>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="chk_docid[]" id="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>" 
         value="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>"></td> ...
```

I have an EDIT Link as a menu in the top in view.php.

```
<a href="editdoc.php>Document</a>
```

**My question : How do I pass the value of the checked checkbox when I click the edit link.**

Note :I searched for a similar question, but could not find one. If I missed any similar question please provide me with the link.

Thanks in advance.
Lakshmi

Note: changed the id of the checkbox from chk_docid to the dynamic row value ($row['docid']) as suggested by Jaak Kütt.

Comment: How many results does your while produce? Make sure you assing a different id="chk_docid" to each of them. I'd go for class="chk_docid" and id="chk_docid<?=$row['docid']?>" or something :)

Comment: Currently it has some 10 rows i'm in a test environment, but the data is expected to be growing in production.(atleast few 100s)..

I guess, I need to rename the id to the value of the docid itself..am i right?

Comment: use some prefix + id since it should only start with a-z or A-Z

Comment: My docid  is a varchar type and by default it starts with alphabets followed by a hyphen(-) and then the numbers. So will it be ok if I directly use the row id as my checkbox id?

Comment: jep, in that case it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your inputs have different id-s..

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  ?>
...<input type="checkbox"  name="chk_docid[]" class="chk_input" 
id="chk_docid<?php echo $row['docid'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>">...
```

using jQuery:

```
<a href="editdoc.php" id="editdoc">Document</a>

$("#editdoc").click(function(){
    var selection=$("input.chk_input:checked");
    if(selection.length){
        var href=$(this).attr('href')+'?'+selection.serialize();
        $(this).attr('href',href);
    }
    return true;
});
```

non-jQuery:

```
<a onclick="submitWithChecked(this,'chk_input')" href="editdoc.php">Document</a>

function submitWithChecked(e,className){
    // fetch all input elements, styled for older browsers
    var elems=document.getElementsByTagName('input');                    
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        // for each input look at only the ones with the class you are intrested in
        if((elems[i].getAttribute('class') === className || elems[i].getAttribute('className') === className) && elems[i].checked){
            // check if you need to add ? or & infront of a query part
            e.href+=(!i && e.href.indexOf('?')<0)?'?':'&';
            // append elements name and value to the query  
            e.href+=elems[i].name+'='+encodeURIComponent(elems[i].value);
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

in editdoc.php fetch the values with php using $_GET['name_of_input_element']

Comment: Thanks Jaak Kütt... I did change the id for the checkbox as you have suggested. 

Regarding the link, can you give me the Javascript version. Im not using JQuery..

Comment: surely, just a moment

Comment: Thanks Jaak Kütt. Im trying to understand what you have given in the function. 

Meanwhile, how do I get the value of the checkbox passed to in the editdoc page?

Comment: added some comments and removed the extra var assingment for href

Comment: I tried giving $_GET['chk_docid']; in editdoc.php and it does not show.Here is what i did.

    <?php
    $cval=$_GET['chk_docid'];
    echo $cval;
    ?>

Comment: print the value of the get by print_r($_GET) to see what has been sent. In your case, since you are using checkboxes $_GET['chk_docid'] should contain an array of the checked values

Comment: i expected the same, but it prints nothing. I'm pasting my code here (the updated one) so that you can help me to solve this problem.
I. My Link to editdoc.php
    <a onclick="submitWithChecked(e,'chk_input')" href="editdoc.php" title="Edit Document">Document</a>
II.My Checkbox:
    <input type="checkbox"  name="chk_docid[]" class="chk_input"
id="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>">
III. For the function, I pasted your code in the Javascript code section of my file.
IV. My editdoc.php starts with 
    <?php $cval=$_GET['chk_docid']; print_r($cval);

Comment: how does this anchor onclick event works. to test whether the onclick event is called, i tried giving an alert function in the starting of your js function and it does not alert at all.. am i missing something here.. here is how i did(im pasting the start alone due to limit in characters here..)

function submitWithChecked(e,className){ alert("hi"); var elems=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); ....

Comment: ah cr** :D you're right. I totally missed that I had accidentally changed "this" into "e" on the <a> elem - it should have been <a onclick="submitWithChecked(this,'chk_input')" href="editdoc.php">Document</a> XD

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!!!

Though I did it in a different way, **I thank  Jaak Kütt for all the support** and helping me to think of a possible way..

This is what I did.. I named the form as showForm and moved to editdoc.php through the function itself.

My Check Box :

```
<form name="showForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_docid[]" id="<?php echo $row['docid'];?>" value="<?  php echo $row['docid'];?>">
```

My Link:

```
<a id="a_editdoc" onclick="getchkVal();" title="Edit Document">Document</a>
```

The corresponding script:

```
<script>
    function getchkVal() {
        var contents, vals = [], mydocid =  document.forms['showForm']['chk_docid[]'];
        for(var i=0,elm;elm = mydocid[i];i++) {
            if(elm.checked) {
                vals.push(encodeURIComponent(elm.value)); 
            }    
        }
        contents = vals.join(',');
        window.location="editdoc.php"+"?v="+contents;     
    }
</script>
```

In the editdoc.php :

```
<?php
    $cval=$_GET['v'];
?>
```

Thanks.