# ICHECK: Pass checkbox value to Edit (using href)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, icheck

Based on same functionality as here:
[Pass checkbox value to Edit (using href)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330367/pass-checkbox-value-to-edit-using-href)

I'm looking to how it can be done if iCheck plugin is enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using multiple submit buttons in a single form.